# Add parameter to MessageBox prompt

Tags: extjs, callback, parameter-passing, extjs4.1

I use this prompt statement and want to pass another variable to callback function:

**Normal behaviour:**

```
Ext.MessageBox.prompt('Name', 'New folder name:', this.callbackCreateFolder);

callbackCreateFolder: function(btn, text) {
         console.log( btn ); // value as expected
         console.log( text ); // value as expected
}
```

**What I want:**

```
Ext.MessageBox.prompt('Name', 'New folder name:', this.callbackCreateFolder(oRecord));
callbackCreateFolder: function(btn, text, oRecord) {
         console.log( btn ); // undefined
         console.log( text ); // undefined
         console.log( oRecord ); // value as expected
}
```

What is the best way to pass additional parameters to the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Ext.require('*');

function foo(btn, text, s1, s2) {
    console.log(s1, s2);
}

Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.MessageBox.prompt('Name', 'New folder name:', Ext.Function.bind(foo, null, ['bar', 'baz'], 2));
});
```